# How to wrap an expanded column with another column?

Tags: flutter

I need to add padding (i.e. a space from screen edgess) for the first two widgets in a body column.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      // need to add padding for the next two widgets
      Container(
        child: Expanded(
          child: Column(...),
        ),
      ),
      Row(...),
      // until here
      Container(
        child: Expanded(
          child: Column(...
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I tried to wrap them in a column again, but that gives the error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded.

I guess the problem is in wrapping the expanded column with new column. How to make that?

Comment: Will adding another Expanded around new column solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap that newly created Column with another Expanded widget.

```
Scaffold(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: Column(...),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(...),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

margin inside Container does what you want
example

```
   Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 10),
      child:....
    )
```

Comment: the idea is to wrap the first two widgets with a column and wrap that column with a container with margin, but the problem is with wraping them with a new column

Comment: add height to your container i think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Bro, you need to wrap your first Column with Container first, or with SizedBox. The requirement is that you cannot set Column within unbounded Width or Height. Otherwise, it will give an error. So set it up first, and set the Expanded inside it.